# Sumbline Text 2, Eclipse all acting up, IndentationError

Tags: python, eclipse, sublimetext2

I'm having a problem with python interpreters. It happened 2nd time in recent months and is very frustrating. This is my code:

[image]

When I run this, the interpreter raises an error:

`else:
        ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

same is occuring on Eclipse.

I typied code by hand, no copy/pase, tried to fix it many times and the error is not subsiding. Although the code is 100% corrent. When I remove `else: pass` part it even sometimes raises `open_odds is not defined` error.

Have you guys had similar problems? Even python IDLE is now acting up on the same code line, the same error. I can no longer work ;/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing tabs and spaces. Don't do that.

Run your script with `python -tt` then fix the errors that finds.

Next, configure your editor to *only* use spaces:

- View -> Indentation -> Indent Using Spaces
- View -> Indentation -> Tab Width: 4
- View -> Indentation -> Convert Indentation to Spaces

and perhaps set that as the default for Python. See [Indentation settings](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/indentation.html) in the Sublime Text 2 documentation.