# How to correct syntax error due to tab order in python?

Tags: python, tabs

I usually experience the problem with tab when programming with Python (when editing the `.py` file with a different editor possibly).

It is so frustrating! that sometimes i want to manually put all the tabs from first line to end of the file if i need to edit.

Is there any better way of solving this problem?

Comment: Don't use different editors? Or make sure they all have the same settings when it comes to tabs/spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, do not use tabs when indenting. It is *too easy* to mix tabs and spaces.

Quoting from the [PEP 8 Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces):

> Never mix tabs and spaces.
>
> The most popular way of indenting Python is with spaces only. The second-most popular way is with tabs only. Code indented with a mixture of tabs and spaces should be converted to using spaces exclusively. When invoking the Python command line interpreter with the -t option, it issues warnings about code that illegally mixes tabs and spaces. When using -tt these warnings become errors. These options are highly recommended!
>
> **For new projects, spaces-only are strongly recommended over tabs. Most editors have features that make this easy to do.**

Emphasis mine.

First, detect inconsistent indentation by running your code with `python -tt scriptname.py`. Fix those errors.

Then convert tabs to spaces, and configure your editor to only use spaces for indentation. The Python Style Guide recommends 4 spaces per indentation level, and so do I.

Comment: in my past 10 years of python programming i am using tab. so am i wrong??

Comment: Are you using tabs in your Python code?  In my experience, you'll run into problems with indentation more often than if you used only spaces.

Comment: this is pretty new to me. i don't know why i took 10years to understand this. thanks for your answer.

Comment: In any case, you can use a replace, I'm sure most editors allow the change easily enough. In any case, I was also using tabs and changed the settings of my editor so that it would automatically add four spaces instead... There is a thousand things that could help you, don't despair!

Comment: but i found python codes in github for example with 4spaced, and not 1spaced

Comment: @suhail: 4 spaces is perfect, that is normal indentation. Configure your editor to use 4 spaces for indentation and you are set.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but in sublime if you put `:` then press enter, then it will automatically create a tab i guess. and 1 more doubt is there any problem with number of space using for-eg(1,2,3,4... spaces for a single intention) and does i need to make it constant through out the project(foreg if i use 3space for intention the through out the project for intention 3space)???

Comment: @suhail: I use Sublime Text. It'll *indent*; you need to configure your indentation to use spaces.

Comment: @suhail: See [Sumbline Test 2, Eclipse all acting up, IndentationError](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17474158)

Answer (score 1):

It's best not to use tabs at all.

Comment: so just use space instead of tabs???

Comment: Yes, most good editors can automatically convert tabs to spaces; so you still have the benefit of using the tab (which is then changed into spaces).

Comment: so what about sublime. in sublime if you put : then press enter, then it will automatically create a tab i guess

Comment: I don't know sublime ... however pressing enter is not needed. As soon as a 'tab' is pressed, automatically spaces are inserted and no tab symbol (so mostly 1 to 4 spaces to go to the next specified indentation).

Answer (score 0):

Use an editor that either

- does not suck
- has the capability to read tags (like vim, emacs or gedit)
- has settings to decide how to indent your code automatically

And additionally you could

- limit yourself to either <kbd>tab</kbd>s or <kbd>space</kbd>s

Answer (score 0):

I use eclipse with pydev plugin

I can tell it once that I use spaces for indentation and that's it

I have not had do this after that at all

Also it has a lot of cool features

Answer (score 0):

do not use tabs spaces are better, and if you want to use an ide than vim or vi, you can choose pycharm you can format all your file with spaces

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions:

1. Either use all tabs or all spaces.
2. If you already have mixed tabs & spaces, convert tabs to spaces. Many editors provide this feature.
3. You can also use linux command `expand` to convert tabs to 'n' spaces. I myself prefer this option, because it's easy to format the code (& any stupid ascii arts or tables) with tabs & THEN convert all tabs to spaces, when done.

Recommended way is obviously 1. "stick to spaces or tabs, don't mix them."